# What are the part numbers for the original brick minifigures?

Tags: minifigures, minifigure-identification

I was gifted two containers of assorted LEGO bricks that had some of these:

[image: Original style LEGO Mini figures]

Apparently these were only made for a few years before the minifigures we know now appeared in 1978. Does anybody know the part number for the legs, torso, and faceless head?

Slightly more info found here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lego_minifigure#History

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are Bricklink entries for the:

- [legs (#15)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=15&name=Legs%20Old&category=%5BMinifig,%20Body%20Part%5D#T=C)
- [torso (#17)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=17&idColor=7#T=C&C=7)
- and [head (#3626a)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3626a&idColor=3#T=C&C=3)